# Retrieving random row from Parse in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Anyone has sample project to fetch random row from parse in Android? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449665/how-to-get-random-rowsparse-objects-from-parse-table-using-android-parse-sdk), but I am unclear about the solution, I have deployed my cloud code, but also unsure if it is working or not and also how it actually works.

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("movie", "The Matrix");

ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new
   FunctionCallback<ParseObject>() {
  void done(ParseObject ratings, ParseException e) {
   if (e == null) {
      // Do your stuff
      }
  }});
```

In params, `movie` and `The Matrix` is used to check matching columns in parse class? What does `averageStars` refers to?

Comment: @Keyul can you explain and share your complete solution please? Thank you.

Comment: averageStars is name of javascript function in Parse Cloud Code whereas "movie" is name of formal parameter pass to that function with value "The Matrix"

Comment: Referring http://stackoverflow.com/a/32316229/3649326, isn't the name of the function is "get10Obj"? So "movie" is referring to a column of parse class and "the matrix" is referring to a value? It is used like a where clause? @virendrao

Comment: Create a query for a the class you want.  Choose a random number less than the number of objects in the class.   Set the query's skip to the random number and set the limit = 1.

Comment: @danh if I want to fetch list of random rows continuously?